# Splitting Vim config into multiple files

Tags: vim, text-editor, vim-plugin

Here is a part of my config:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" Here I want to split my Vim config into multiple files
" I'm including other Vim configuration files

for f in glob('.vim/*.vim', 0, 1)
    execute 'source' f
endfor

call plug#end()
```

And it works perfect from home directory.

But when I'm running Vim from directory with my project (e.g. `cd ~/Dev/my-project && vim`) all my configuration and plugins from `~/.vim/*.vim` files not works.

Vim uses only configuration from `~/.vimrc`. And `execute` not works

How can I solve this problem? I want to split my Vim config into multiple files

Comment: What is the path of your directory `plug` ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス`~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim`

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックスLooks like it's not `vim-plug` problem. If I put `set number` for example into `~/.vim/snippets.vim` I will see no line numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for f in glob('~/.vim/*.vim', 0, 1)
    execute 'source' f
endfor
```

Answer (score 4):

Put your files into `$HOME/.vim/plugin`, this is what this is for. You may also want to have a look at ftplugins, etc.

I'm quite sure that there is somewhere on SO or on vi.SE a Q/A describing best practices regarding how to split one's config into multiple files.

Comment: This, plus using the rtp structures effectively

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the function *globpath()*. Just like:

```
for f in globpath('~/.vim', '*.vim', 0, 1, 0)
    execute 'source' f
endfor
```